# Return array based on titles

Tags: excel

I'm, looking for a way to return an array of text based off of titles or headers if you will. My brain isn't working today and I keep struggling to find the best method. I originally was going to have a bunch of IF statements and ran into problems, and I can't seem to figure out if Aggregate is a viable method.

[image]

Essentially if "Title 1" is selected from a drop down I would like to return the names within Title 1, and so on. If "All" is selected I would like all to populate from each title. The speed bumps I have is that some names repeat and I only want to show each name once always in alphabetical order. Can someone please get me started on how to tackle this?

Comment: This is Difficult unless there is someway to know what is a title and what is not.  Do you have a distinct list of titles?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: @ScottCraner, I suppose OP should have that list if he's indeed working with a validation list in drop-down

Comment: So this project is from scratch, I was originally thinking a validation list of specific titles. Using Office 365

Comment: What I mean from "scratch" is that this was the best way for me to illustrate what I was looking to do, but a better method is always appreciated. Maybe a VLOOKUP with each "name" listed and then every column next to it lists out the titles they fall under?\

Comment: Is your data in a single column like portrayed?  If so, you will need a comprensive list of the titles.  Excel does not know which text is a title and which are parts.  Unless you can come up with a specific rule, there is no way for excel to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel O365 with the `FILTER` function, you can do this with a helper column (which you can hide, or position elsewhere).

I created a Table and am using structured references, but you can change to ordinary addressing if you prefer.

`TitleList` is a named range that includes all or your titles (presumeably you will use this for your dropdown).

For the Helper Column, I have it adjacent to your Names column with the formula:

```
=IF(OR(A2=TitleList),ROW(),B1)
```

This creates a unique number for each title.

Then, for your formula, under the dropdown, you can use:

```
=FILTER(Table3[Names],(Table3[Names]<>G1)* (Table3[Index]=XLOOKUP(G1,Table3[Names],Table3[Index])))
```

where `G1` contains the dropdown

With Column B visible:

[image]

*Some with O365 do not have the `FILTER` function. If you do not have the `FILTER` function, you can use:*

```
=INDEX(Table3[Names],AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(INDEX(Table3[Index],MATCH(G1,Table3[Names],0))=Table3[Index])*ROW(Table3)-ROW(Table3[#Headers]),ROW(INDEX($A:$A,2):INDEX($A:$A,COUNTIF(Table3[Index],INDEX(Table3[Index],MATCH(G1,Table3[Names],0)))))))
```

**EDIT**

To return a non-duplicate list of ALL of the names, add `ALL` to `TitleList` and use this formula instead.

*This formula makes a special case for `ALL` and filters out the rows that contain a `Title`*

```
=IF(G1="ALL",UNIQUE(FILTER(Table3[Names],COUNTIF(TitleList,Table3[Names])=0)),FILTER(Table3[Names],(Table3[Names]<>G1)*(Table3[Index]=XLOOKUP(G1,Table3[Names],Table3[Index]))))
```

[image].imgur.com/apkHh.png

Comment: Awesome stuff! This looks like it will work perfectly, is there a way to have it return all values (ignoring duplicates) when a general query is selected? Such that if I just select "Title" from the drop down list then it populates with all Names?

Comment: @KevinP. See my Edit.